# Spark dataframe: Merged data with python results in a very large number of rows

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, azure-databricks

Pyspark: A merged data (using Left join) rusults in a very large number of rows. Why are there too many resulting rows after merger? Is there anything seriously wrong with my code? Both dataframes have one common key 'Region'.

- 1st dataframe (df1): 47,972 rows
- 2nd dataframe (df2): 852,747 rows
- Merged_df: 10,836,925,792 rows

```
merged_df = df1.join(df2, on=['Region'] , how = 'left')
merged_df = df1.join(df2, on=['Region'] , how = 'left')
```

I am expecting more rows but in billions.

Comment: LEFT JOIN can return multiple copies of the data from dataframe1, if the foreign key for a row in dataframe1 is referenced by multiple rows in dataframe2.

Comment: `47,972 x 852,747 = 40,907,979,084` so how is `10,836,925,792` a surprise?!

Answer (score 1):

Let assume two dataframes:

[image]

The left join result is:

[image]

**In other words, a LEFT JOIN indicates that all records from the LEFT (first) dataframe will be returned, regardless of whether they are present in the RIGHT dataframe. If the right dataframe does not include any matches, the result is null.**

For every region in first dataframe it will return all matching regions in second dataframe.

> AS kasyap said the probability of getting maximum rows is `47,972 x 852,747 = 40,907,979,084` if Region column is same in both dataframe.